# Can I control the format of Excel files generated by Business Central?

Tags: export-to-excel, dynamics-business-central

My users love the "Send to Excel" feature of Business Central, and of NAV before it; however they have a request, and I've got no clue how to answer it.

Some pages send their data to Excel in a standard .xlsx formatted file; other pages output a file in "XML Spreadsheet 2003" format. For some purposes, the XML format is actually preferred, and we're looking for how we can control which format is used for particular pages. However, for the life of me I can't find out if this is something we can control, or what the criteria are that decide which format will be used.

Can anyone give us some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Are they using the "Open in Excel" or "Edit in Excel" from a Business Central page, or are they using the "Send To" function when running a report? There are a few different options available to the user when running a report, and I see the XML document there (see image below).

[image: Choose file type for "Send To" when generating a report in Business Central]

If you could give a little more clarity as to which specific page they are using, that would be helpful.